# Booking form PHP not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm attempting to make an enquiry form on my site send an email regarding a booking. But I cannot work out my mistake in the PHP, very much a beginner to PHP so don't know where I went wrong.

I receive no email when testing the form on server.

```
<?php 

$firstname = $_post['firstname'];
$lastname = $_post['lastname'];
$bandname = $_post['bandname'];
$email = $_post['email'];
$phoneno = $_post['phoneno'];
$startday = $_post['start_day'];
$startmonth = $_post['start_month'];
$starthour = $_post['start_hour'];
$startminute = $_post['start_minute'];
$endday = $_post['end_day'];
$endmonth = $_post['end_month'];
$endhour = $_post['end_hour'];
$endminute = $_post['end_minute'];
$extras = $_post['extras'];

$to = "some@emailaddress.com";
$subject = "New Message";

mail ($to, $subject, $firstname . $lastname, $bandname, $email, $phoneno, $start_day . $start_month, $start_hour . $start_minute, $end_day . $end_month, $end_hour . $end_minute, $extras);
?>
```

HTML of my form :

```
                       <form action="form.php" class="appnitro" id="form_1062945" method="post" name="form_1062945" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <div class="form_description medium-8 small-10 columns medium-centered small-centered" style="margin-bottom:45px">
                                <p>
                                    Please complete the form below to send us details of the booking you would like to make, we will then get back to you within one business day to confirm your booking.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <ul>
                                <li class="small-6 columns" id="li_1">
                                    <label class="description" for="element_1">First Name</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="element text medium" id="element_1" maxlength="255" name="firstname" type="text" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="small-6 columns" id="li_2">
                                    <label class="description" for="element_2">Last Name</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="element text medium" id="element_2" maxlength="255" name="lastname" type="text" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="small-6 columns" id="li_3">
                                    <label class="description" for="element_3">Company/band/artist</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="element text medium" id="element_3" maxlength="255" name="bandname" type="text" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="small-6 columns" id="li_8">
                                    <label class="description" for="element_8">Email</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="element text medium" id="element_8" maxlength="255" name="email" type="text" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="small-6 end columns" id="li_4">
                                    <label class="description" for="element_4">Phone number</label>
                                    <div>
                                        <input class="element text medium" id="element_4" maxlength="255" name="phoneno" type="text" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="small-12 columns">

                                        <li class="small-12 columns text-left" id="li_11">
                                            <label class="description" for="element_11_1">Which space(s) are you interested in?</label>

                                            <div class="line-boxes">
                                                <span>
                                                    <input class="element checkbox" id="element_11_1" name="studio_1" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                                    <label class="choice" for="element_11_1">Studio 1</label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="line-boxes">
                                                <span><input class="element checkbox" id="element_11_2" name="studio_2" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                                    <label class="choice" for="element_11_2" style="margin-bottom:20px">Studio 2</label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>

                                        </li>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <li class="small-12 medium-6 columns lose-pad" id="li_6">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_6_1">Start Date</label>

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_6_1" maxlength="2" name="start_day" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_6_1" style="font-size:10px">DD</label>
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_6_2" maxlength="2" name="start_month" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_6_2" style="font-size:10px">MM</label>
                                    </span>

                                </li>

                                <li class="medium-6 small-12 columns lose-pad" id="li_5">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_5_1">Start Time</label> 

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_5_1" maxlength="2" name="start_hour" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_5_1" style="font-size:10px">HH</label>
                                    </span> 

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_5_2" maxlength="2" name="start_minute" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_5_2" style="font-size:10px">MM</label>
                                    </span>

                                </li>

                                <li class="small-12 medium-6 columns lose-pad" id="li_9">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_9_2">End Date</label> 

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_9_2" maxlength="2" name="end_day" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_9_2" style="font-size:10px">DD</label>
                                    </span> 

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">

                                        <input class="element text" id="element_9_1" maxlength="2" name="end_month" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_9_1" style="font-size:10px">MM</label>
                                    </span> 

                                </li>

                                <li class="medium-6 small-12 columns lose-pad" id="li_7">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_7_1">End Time</label> <span class="small-6 columns">

                                    <input class="element text" id="element_7_1" maxlength="2" name="end_hour" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                    <label for="element_7_1" style="font-size:10px">HH</label>
                                    </span> 

                                    <span class="small-6 columns">
                                        <input class="element text" id="element_7_2" maxlength="2" name="end_minute" size="2" type="text" value=""> 
                                        <label for="element_7_2" style="font-size:10px">MM</label>
                                    </span>

                                </li>

                                <li class="small-12 columns text-left" id="li_12">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_12_1" style="margin-top:20px">Do you require or interested in any of the following additional services?</label> 
                                    <div class="line-boxes" style="margin-top:20px">
                                        <span><input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_1" name="console_wedges" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_1">House monitor console and wedges?</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="line-boxes">
                                        <span>
                                            <input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_2" name="iem" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_2">IEM System rental?</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="line-boxes">
                                        <span>
                                            <input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_3" name="chairs" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_3">Chairs?</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="line-boxes">
                                        <span>
                                            <input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_4" name="stools" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_4">Stools?</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="line-boxes">
                                        <span>
                                            <input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_5" name="backline" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_5">Backline rental?</label>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="line-boxes">
                                        <span>
                                            <input class="element checkbox" id="element_12_6" name="transport" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
                                            <label class="choice" for="element_12_6" style="margin-bottom:30px">Transport of equipment to or from Ritz</label>                                              </span>
                                    </div>

                                </li>

                                <li class="small-12 columns" id="li_10">

                                    <label class="description" for="element_10">Anything else we should know to help assist with your booking?</label>

                                    <div>
                                        <textarea class="element textarea small" id="element_10" name="extras"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="buttons small-6 columns small-centered">
                                    <input name="form_id" type="hidden" value="1062945">
                                    <input class="button_text" id="saveForm" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </form>
```

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: apologies @Jezzabeanz edited now, I was receiving no mail from the form

Comment: You are passing wrong parameters to mail function. Please check php mail function for parameters http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: there is no form action so, unless the php on top is in the same file as your form, it has never been called.

Comment: @JulioSoares `action="form.php"`

Comment: Gawd, if it ever makes it there. You have so many syntax errors here.

Comment: Sad I was very new to PHP and ran my code through a validator to check for errors and got none. So again my apologies, very new at this

Comment: @MikeSmith I highly recommend `codetuts`  website as well as reading various books on the subject of PHP but the most useful place for you would be ***http://www.php.net/manual/*** which is a massive manual of every native PHP function and library and will be invaluable as a reference guide for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, all your `$_post` are incorrect.

That is a superglobal and must read as `$_POST`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Then you're injecting too many parameters in your `mail()` function.

Please read the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Your server may not be setup to catch and display/log errors/notices/warnings.

Having used error reporting, would have thrown you many notices.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: thank you for this, very helpful, was not aware of the limitations within the mail function

Comment: @MikeSmith You're most welcome Mike.